# What is the difference between apache modules with and without the ".c" extension?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am running apache v2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and have containers/directives this format

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        # ...
</IfModule>
```

However I often see modules referenced in apache official documentation and in stackexchange sites this way:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
        # ...
</IfModule>
```

Ive searched alot, including **here** - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule and Im unable to find what the difference is and when one is supposed to be used over the other?

---

#### Take the rewrite module for example

From the apache [documentation: ifmodule directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule)

> The module argument can be either the module identifier or the file
>   name of the module, at the time it was compiled.
>   For example,
>   rewrite_module is the identifier and mod_rewrite.c is the file name.

And its very common to see this in `.htaccess` files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # ....
</IfModule>
```

Ive `grep`'ed my `/etc/apache2` directory and "mod_rewrite.c" isn't defined anywhere.

On my machine the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load`
contains:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

so is `mod_rewrite.c` a reference to a windows/other file? in which case referring to it on a linux machine would be incorrect syntax?

Comment: The page you link to clearly shows the difference in the two schemes: One is the module identifier, the other is the source file name that the module was compiled from.

Comment: @DanielLawson, you've pointed out the difference between the module identifier and the source file name. My question is: *What is the difference between apache modules with and without the “.c” extension?*, thanks

Comment: I have elaborated further in an answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the page you [linked](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule) to, it contains this text:

> The module argument can be either the module identifier or the file name of the module, at the time it was compiled. For example, rewrite_module is the identifier and mod_rewrite.c is the file name. If a module consists of several source files, use the name of the file containing the string STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF.

Using the example provided, the rewrite module can either be referred to as 'rewrite_module' (identifier) or mod_rewrite.c (filename). Both are equivalent, and there is no difference. You can use either.

The module with the source file mod_rewrite.c, gets compiled into mod_rewrite.so, which is what you'll have on your filesystem. This source file has the line 'module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA rewrite_module;' in it, which declares a module called 'rewrite_module'.

The module can be referred to either as 'rewrite_module', which is the identifier, or 'mod_rewrite.c', which is the source file it was compiled from.

The 'LoadModule' line tells it to load the module with the identifier 'rewrite_module' from the already-compiled object mod_rewrite.so.  When you configure this, you can either refer to the identifier or the source file name if you know it.

Comment: that explains perfectly thanks. I've never seen a reference to a files pre-compiled file name before so it wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielLawson already pointed out, this is clearly described in the Apache manual page you're linking to.

> The module argument can be either the module identifier or the file name of the module, at the time it was compiled.

The file name of the module ends with a *.c* extension, as C is the language Apache httpd is developed in.

A concept of module identifiers is, in turn, similar to Stack Exchange's tags. Your `<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>` block reads: if you have any module tagged as *mpm_prefork_module*. This allows for better flexibility in config - different modules offering the same functionality, like *mod_ssl.c* and *mod_gnutls.c* both have *ssl_module* identifier.

Comment: thanks, but as per the previous comments, what I am trying to find out is *What is the difference between apache modules with and without the “.c” extension?*. e.g. the `mod_rewrite.c` doesn't seem to exist in my system as a file or a identifier, so therefore would it be wrong for me to reference `mod_rewrite.c` in a directive?

Comment: It relates to the module **source** file - it has *.c* extension.

Comment: I see now, thanks (upvoted). I have never seen a pre-compilation file being referred to before so I wasn't "getting it". In that case I  assume that referring to `mod_rewrite.c` would work fine on my system as well as other operating systems then too

Comment: The practice of referring source file name (and optionally also position) is not uncommon, especially in error messages, exceptions, etc.